# Routing message from AWS API Gateway to SQS regarding URL path

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-sqs

I need to route a message from API Gateway to a specific queue regarding URL Path.

By example:

/queues/{queueId} -> API GW routes /queues/queue1 URL to SQS queue1

Is it possible to do it "simply" only with API GW config or do I need to use a lambda to make the routing to the right queue ? or any other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do that.

While configuring integration on `Path Override` you need define it like `12345678/{queueId}` (12345678 is your account id).

Then you need to define `URL PATH Parameters`

- **Name** `queueId`, **Mapped from** `method.request.path.queueId`
- Expand **HTTP headers** add new Header with **Name** `Content-Type`, **Mapped from** as `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`
- Add a **Mapping Templates** as *Content-Type* `application/json` and template body as `Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=$input.body`